# How to disallow user to register with a specific word in the username?

Tags: user-registration

It's since 1 month ago, every day we'll receive some tens of new user registration with username containing like `YggrnCyhorgeVH` or `AurizarCyhorgeVH`, etc..

Ip and user agent are different every time, so I thinked to avoid user registration with this name.

**Is there a hook/action/filter where to intercept the user registration and deny it?**

PLEASE do not suggests plugin/captcha or others. I made a specific question.

Comment: Have you tried a captcha? This would filter out most automated bots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code should work for you, but I can not guarantee that because your form is so heavily (and badly) customized. I have tested it on not customized registration form and it worked just fine.

```
function cyhorge_check_fields( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    if ( preg_match('/(CyhorgeVH)/', $sanitized_user_login ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'username_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: User contains CyhorgeVH string.', 'my_textdomain' ) );
    }

    return $errors;
}

add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'cyhorge_check_fields', 10, 3 );
```

[SOURCE](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/registration_errors)

**EDIT:** Another possible solution:

```
function prevent_cyhorge_user( $user_login, $user_email, $errors ) {

    if ( strpos( $user_login, 'CyhorgeVH' ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'username_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: User contains CyhorgeVH string.', 'my_textdomain' ) );
    }

}

add_action( 'register_post', 'prevent_cyhorge_user', 10, 3 );
```

Notice that the second function is using `strpos` instead of `preg_match` which probably a bit faster, but `preg_match` provides more flexibility if needed.

Both should work from either theme's `functions.php` or as a plugin.

Comment: Thanks, I was exactly looking for an hook like "registration_errors" !

Answer (score 0):

Get spam filters for your site - captcha, Wordfence etc. General security helps against stuff like this.

Comment: I cannot, my login form is customized, heavily customized, very BAD customized (I'm not guilty). I asked how to intercept registration event and interrupt it if I want.